# Ubuntu for Android on Samsung Galaxy Note

Tags: android, samsung

Will Ubuntu for Android work on a Samsung Galaxy Note. And if so, where can I get a decent docking device with HDMI and usb interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a version for the N7000:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/n7000

And here is a list for supported devices:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

But I think the pen will not work.

I haven't tried yet but i will try on my Galaxy Note too.

There is a HDMI converter for the Samsung galaxy Note. But I haven't heard about a docking station.

For the HDMI-Convertor google for: ET-H10FAUWEGWW HDMI-Adapter